# Not able to draw rectangle on bottom corner of Screen

Tags: android, android-canvas, ondraw

Not able to draw a rectangle on the bottom corner of Screen when I am in full-screen mode means no status bar is visible and no navigation bar is visible

```
Display mdisp = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point mdispSize = new Point();
mdisp.getSize(mdispSize);
int maxX = mdispSize.x; 
int maxY = mdispSize.y;

@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
                            canvas.drawRect(0, maxY-pixel, pixel, MaxY);
           }
```

by using this code I am not able to put that rectangle in the bottom corner, the rectangle always appears to be above the area which is a reserve for the navigation bar.
[image: corner]

Comment: Since you're in fullscreen what's wrong with the rectangle at the bottom of the screen

Comment: i will attach a picture take a look at that

Comment: @ManojPerumarath please have a look

Comment: there are two types of triangle , one is blue and black?

Comment: blue ones are made using xml and black ones are programmatically by using display coordinates

Comment: Where do you actually need that rectangle

Comment: At bottom corner like blue one .

Comment: its done ,it was the problem of Sticky immersive navigation bar ,i had to add full screen Flag in

Comment: final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
   decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
     if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
      decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
     }
    }
   });

Answer (score 0):

This is in Kotlin but it can show you how to achieve this:

```
class MyView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : View(context, attributeSet) {
    private var mHeight = 0
    private var mWidth = 0

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        canvas?.drawRect(mWidth-100, mHeight-100, mWidth, mHeight)
    }

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom)
        mHeight = bottom - top
        mWidth = right - left
    }
}
```